# JS/AJAX: Refresh part of a page on the click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently in the midst of creating a generator which echoes a random line from a .txt file. All is well and good however I need to have this certain part of the page which echoes the random line refresh when a button is clicked. I've tried multiple methods to no avail and I'm running out of ideas - I'm still quite new to JavaScript/AJAX and have no idea on how to go about it. Any help would be brilliant, thanks!

Comment: What are the multiple methods you have tried? This seems like simple enough to do with an AJAX call and then modify the relavant HTML portion in the call back method.

Comment: methods which use period reloads, then through minor editing to allow it to do so on the click of a button. Again I have close to no clue on what I'm doing so I may/probably have messed up somewhere along the lines.

Comment: Do you use some external js libraries like jquery or so? Or do you want to implement it in native js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery Ajax to get contents from the file and display the contents into a div

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "yourfilename.txt"
  }).done(function( msg ) {
  $("#YOURDIVID").html(msg.d);
});
```

Bind click event of your button

```
$(function(){
  $("#YOURBUTTONID").on("click",function(){
    //do your work
  });
});
```

Refreshing logic can be wrapped into a function and called on click of button OR you can use javascript settimeout method.